# pandas rank function 2 columns for high and low values

Tags: python, pandas

Here's some code to make up a pandas dataframe with 2 columns one called `data` and the other called `hours`. The `data` column is random int from -150 to 250. And the `hours` column is random floats from .5 to 15.5.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.randint(-150,250,size=200)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Data'])


#generate random floats for df2
randomFloatList = []
# Set a length of the list to length of pandas df1
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    # any random float between 5.50 to 50.50
    x = round(random.uniform(0.50, 15.50), 2)
    randomFloatList.append(x)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(randomFloatList,columns=['hours'])


combined = df.join(df2)
print(combined)
```

Returns:

```
     Data  hours
0      93   9.66
1      85  14.76
2     -82  12.55
3     -44   2.40
4      -1  13.86
```

Can Pandas rank function reorganize a dataframe based on the highest values in one column (`data`) and lowest values in a different column (`hours`) with rows in the dataset being preserved? Hopefully this makes sense...

If I use
`print(combined.rank(axis='columns'))`

This returns something unwanted, I cant quite figure out if this is possible with the pandas rank or not.

```
     Data  hours
0     2.0    1.0
1     2.0    1.0
2     1.0    2.0
3     1.0    2.0
4     1.0    2.0
```

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: well to have a pandas dataframe ranked while preserving row order for highest values in the `data` column and lowest values found in the `hours` column. Hopefully that makes sense. in my real world application I am trying to find "spikes" in the data

Answer (score 0):

combined['hours_rank'] = combined['hours'].rank(ascending=1)
combined['Data_rank'] =  combined['Data'].rank(ascending=1)

In Data
Data  hours
0   174   0.89
1   226   7.41
2   -90  13.79
3   148   3.02

Out Data
Data  hours  hours_rank  Data_rank
0   174   0.89         1.0        3.0
1   226   7.41         3.0        4.0
2   -90  13.79         4.0        1.0
3   148   3.02         2.0        2.0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrUIZ.png)

Comment: Hello can you edit your post so use `around your code?` hard to read

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code samples. It will make it easier reading your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because Pandas employ an `internal aligning mechanism` based on index , your problem can be tricky to solve. But , by using a vanilla `python list` you can do your sorting job and then assign also the corresponding ranks in your dataframe. If I have understand correctly your issue. Here is a code that does the job :

```
combined['Data']=combined['Data'].sort_values(ascending=False).tolist()
combined['hours']=combined['hours'].sort_values().tolist()
combined['Data_rank'] = combined['Data'].rank()
combined['hours_rank'] = combined['hours'].rank()
```

**Output:**

```
     Data   hours    Data_rank     hours_rank
0     242   0.61      199.5         1.0
1     242   0.71      199.5         2.0
2     241   0.82      198.0         3.0
3     238   0.88      197.0         4.0
4     236   1.01      196.0         5.0
..    ...    ...        ...         ...
195  -144  15.21        5.0       196.0
196  -145  15.22        4.0       197.0
197  -150  15.24        2.0       198.0
198  -150  15.34        2.0       199.0
199  -150  15.35        2.0       200.0

[200 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Hello does this preserve row order?

Comment: Can you specify what exactly do you mean by preserving row order ? Your question also is a bit unclear at this part. Consider putting a code block example in the question, showing the expected output. Anyway my answer is clear, the row order is ascending based on hours values and desceding based on Data values.

Comment: The rows in the data is important. Its almost like a time series data process where two columns represent events happening simulteniously.

Comment: A ok I got it . Yeah I don't know if there is a formal way of dealing with a problem like this or if you have searched for it. But as a fast idea . You can define a threshold for both Data and hours. For example their mean values . And then apply a weighted sum of the row values with weights corresponding how much below or above the value of threshold is . And give a rewarding weight to the Data value above the threshold and a punishing weight to the hours value above the threshold. And then sort this sum , maintain their index and reconstuct the new dataframe